# delete rows based on data frame year and month

Tags: python, pandas

I know this question has probably been asked in someway, but new to python and still having trouble. I had an incomplete data pull from April 2020 and now I'm trying to delete the April 2020 data from the data frame and/or create a new data frame without April 2020 included.

I converted the date time to year and month.
dataframe: cdf2
So far created a mask:

```
cdf2['year']=pd.DatatimeIndex(cdf2['Invoice Paid Date']).year
cdf2['month']=pd.DatatimeIndex(cdf2['Invoice Paid Date']).month
mask= cdf2=cdf2[(cdf2['year']==2020.0) & (cdf2['month']==4.0)]
```

Was trying to do `cdf3=cdf2[~mask]`, but that doesn't work

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: simply `cdf2[~((cdf2['year']==2020.0) & (cdf2['month']==4.0))]` not working?

Comment: @SayandipDutta Thank you. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

First, I created a test data frame, with dates in March, April and May.

```
import pandas as pd

invoice_date = pd.date_range(start='2020-03-01', end='2020-05-15', freq='14d')
amt = [100 + i for i in range(len(invoice_date))]
df = pd.DataFrame({'invoice_date': invoice_date, 'amt': amt})
print(df)

  invoice_date  amt
0   2020-03-01  100
1   2020-03-15  101
2   2020-03-29  102
3   2020-04-12  103
4   2020-04-26  104
5   2020-05-10  105
```

Then, I created and applied a boolean mask.  I used dates in the mask.  I didn't create new columns for month and year.

```
mask = ('2020-04-01' <= df['invoice_date']) & (df['invoice_date'] <= '2020-04-30')
trimmed = df[~ mask]
print(trimmed)

  invoice_date  amt
0   2020-03-01  100
1   2020-03-15  101
2   2020-03-29  102
5   2020-05-10  105
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried your method but the April month from 2020 was still there when using trimmed.tail(). So, I ended up using  Sayandip Dutta's method from above.